# Javascript: compare array element properties, and if identical, combine

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm dealing with an array of objects. Each object has two properties, size and count.

```
var drives = [
{size:"900GB", count:3},
{size:"900GB", count:100},
{size:"1200GB", count:5},
{size:"900GB", count:1}
]
```

I don't like how the same size comes multiple times, and would like to consolidate all repeated sizes into just 1 array index.

First I have the array sorted by size. Then I tried making a for-loop to do manage repetitions.

```
drives.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
var First = parseInt(obj1.size)
var Second = parseInt(obj2.size)
// Ascending: first size less than the previous
return First - Second;
})


for(var i = 0; i < drives.length-1; i++)
 {

    if(drives[i].size == drives[i+1].size)
     {
        drives[i+1].count+=drives[i].count; 
        //add the count of the first index to the second index's count
        drives.splice(i, 1); 
        //delete the first index
     }
 }
```

https://jsbin.com/zayofiqoke/edit?js,console

The for-loop doesn't seem to iterate correctly. It only combines two indexes. How do I achieve what I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This could possibly be made even shorter using `Array#filter`. Credit to [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376639/7256039) for posting the first answer using this strategy. I am using the second argument to the `filter` function, which sets the `this` context given to the passed callback, to use as few extra lines as possible.

```js
var drives = [
  {size:"900GB", count:3},
  {size:"900GB", count:100},
  {size:"1200GB", count:5},
  {size:"900GB", count:1}
]

var result = drives.filter(function (e) {
  if (e.size in this) this[e.size].count += e.count
  else return this[e.size] = e
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

---

**Original:** A better approach might be to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var drives = [
  {size:"900GB", count:3},
  {size:"900GB", count:100},
  {size:"1200GB", count:5},
  {size:"900GB", count:1}
]

var map = drives.reduce(function (map, e) {
  if (e.size in map) map[e.size].count += e.count
  else map[e.size] = e
  return map
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(map).map(function (k) {
  return this[k]
}, map)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array and update the same sized items with a closure over a hash table.

```js
var drives = [{ size: "900GB", count: 3 }, { size: "900GB", count: 100 }, { size: "1200GB", count: 5 }, { size: "900GB", count: 1 }];

drives = drives.filter(function (hash) {
    return function (a) {
        if (!hash[a.size]) {
            hash[a.size] = a;
            return true;
        }
        hash[a.size].count += a.count;
    };
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(drives);
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best implementation but you could always keep a temporary list of elements and iterate through it:

```
var tmp = {};
var out = [];
for(var i = 0; i < drives.length; i++) {
    if(!tmp[JSON.stringify(drives[i])]) {
        out.push(drives[i]);
        tmp[JSON.stringify(drives[i])] = true;
    }
}
```

All I'm doing is iterating through the array, I convert the object to JSON and use that as a key in an object so if there's any identical objects, they will hopefully be caught because they exist in the temporary object (keeps lookup at ~O(1) stringify does iterate over the keys in a loop).

If the key hasn't been defined push the object to a new array and continue to the end of your original array.

So your final solution runs in O(n) but it isn't very memory efficient.